# How to show all the sample principal component plots in R?

Tags: r, pca

I noticed something in R, say `pc` is the result of applying PCA to a data matrix and
`pc$x` is my sample principal component matrix.

When trying `plot(pc$x)`, it will only plot the first principal component (`pc1`) against the second (`pc2`), but I actually have more than 2 principal components. How do I show all of them?

Answer (score 2):

All combinations in a single plot:

```
pairs(pc$x)
```

To select a specific combination just use:

```
plot(pc$x[, c(1,3)])  # e.g. pc1 and pc3
```

Comment: Is there a way I can combine  plot  with the rep function to plot for all  principal components at once ?

Comment: No, what's wrong with pairs()? You probably want something like `matplot(pc$x[,1], pc$x[,-1], pch=19)`.

Comment: pairs(pc$x) works well, but the problem is just that I have to many prinicpal components and the plots look very small , if I plot them all at once on 1 page .

Comment: how about

for (i in 2:ncol(x)) {
   for (j in i:(i-1)) {
       plot(pc$x[,c(j,i)]) 
}}

?